# Get ActorRef from scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.ActorRef]

Tags: scala, playframework, akka

I am attempting to pass an ActorRef to a calling client. Here is some code:

```
object Sub {
  implicit val timeout = Timeout(5 seconds)
  lazy val default = {
    val subActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[Sub], "sub")
    subActor
  }

  def apply(pChannel: Concurrent.Channel[JsValue]):ActorRef = {
    (default ? Register(callback)).map {
      case ref:ActorRef => ref
    } 
  }
}
```

The client invoking this is simply calling `val sub:ActorRef = Sub(channel)`

The problem I get here however is:

```
[error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[akka.actor.ActorRef]
[error]  required: akka.actor.ActorRef
```

How can I modify the code above to get an ActorRef for the calling code to get the ref it needs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Future` is the promise of a certain value at a later time. In this case `Future[ActorRef]` is a value that represents an ActorRef now or at some point in the future.

You don't really want to get the ActorRef directly, you probably want to compose your calling code with the future that is returned.

For instance, if your code does:

```
val sub = Sub(channel)
doSomething(sub)
```

you'd want to rewrite it as:

```
Sub(channel).map { sub =>
  doSomething(sub)
}
```

as that will create a new future that automatically calls `doSomething(sub)` when the `sub` value is available. You can also rewrite the example as:

```
for(sub <- Sub(channel)) yield doSomething(sub)
```

---

If you're looking to block in the calling code and return the value when available (which goes against the design principles of Akka, Play and reactive programming in general), you can always use `Await`, such as:

```
// Await.result() takes a Future[T] and returns a T
val sub = Await.result(Sub(channel), 10 seconds)
```

but it is poor design to do this in library code and isn't recommended. You should only wait on futures at the very end of your processing, and even then, the framework will usually handle that for you.

Comment: I see that await is a part of api.test package. Will it work fine on a production code too? Say for e.g. to implement long polling

Comment: Await is not part of api.test. See `scala.concurrent.Await`